# Algorithm to group messages by time

Tags: javascript, algorithm, date, timestamp

I need to sort messages in the following order: Received `Today`, `Yesterday`, and `This Week`

Rules for `This Week`: starts at the most recent Monday - not including `Today` or `Yesterday`

Meaning:

If `Today` is Sunday, `Yesterday` is Saturday, `This Week` is Friday, Thursday, Wednesday, Tuesday and Monday

If `Today` is Thursday, `Yesterday` is Wednesday, `This Week` is Tuesday and Monday

But if `Today` is Tuesday, `Yesterday` is Monday -- `This Week` has no days

And if `Today` is Monday, `Yesterday` is Sunday -- `This Week` has no days

I have been struggling figuring out how to solve `This Week`. I keep getting bugs and there are so many edge cases to consider as well.

Here's my attempt:

```
var currentDate = new Date()
var currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth()+1
var currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear()
var currentDayofMonth = currentDate.getDate()
var currentDayofWeek = currentDate.getDay()
messages.forEach((message, index) => {
   var date = message.date.substring(0, 10).replace(/-/g, '\/')
   var messageDate = new Date(date)
   var messageMonth = messageDate.getMonth()+1;
   var messageYear = messageDate.getFullYear();
   var messageDayOfMonth = messageDate.getDate();
   var messageDayOfWeek = messageDate.getDay();

   //TODAY
   if(currentDayofMonth == messageDayOfMonth && currentMonth == messageMonth && currentYear == messageYear) {
     messageTypeList["Today"].push(message)
     return
   }

   //YESTERDAY
   if(currentDayofMonth == messageDayOfMonth+1 && currentMonth == messageMonth && currentYear == messageYear) {
     messageTypeList["Yesterday"].push(message)
     return
   }

    //THIS WEEK
    if(currentDayofWeek != 1 && currentDayofWeek != 2 && currentMonth == messageMonth && currentYear == messageYear) {
      messageTypeList["This Week"].push(message)
      return
    }
})
```

Any ideas?

**Note**

I believe I have an edge case bug in `Yesterday` -- For example If `Today` is May 1, it will not count April 30 as `Yesterday` because the month is different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could prepare the ground better by preparing some dates related to today's date:

- Truncate the current date to midnight
- Get the date of yesterday
- Get the date of last Monday

Then compare the message date with each of these 3 dates: the first one that comes on or before the message date determines the category of the message. If all three are greater than the message date, nothing needs to happen.

Here is the suggested code:

```js
// This sample uses a fixed date so the categories can be illustrated better:
var currentDate = new Date('2017/04/27') // Or leave out the argument for actual date
currentDate.setHours(0,0,0,0); // set to midnight
// Prepare all related dates: yesterday and last Monday
var keys = [];
keys.push(['Today', new Date(currentDate)]); // clone
currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - 1);
keys.push(['Yesterday', new Date(currentDate)]); // clone
currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - (currentDate.getDay()+6)%7);
keys.push(['This week', new Date(currentDate)]); // clone

var messages = [
    { date: '2017-04-21' },
    { date: '2017-04-22' },
    { date: '2017-04-23' },
    { date: '2017-04-24' }, // Monday
    { date: '2017-04-25' },
    { date: '2017-04-26' },
    { date: '2017-04-27' },
];

var messageTypeList = {
    Today: [],
    Yesterday: [],
    "This week": []
};

messages.forEach( message => {
    var date = message.date.substring(0, 10).replace(/-/g, '\/');
    var messageDate = new Date(date);
    var [key] = keys.find( ([key, date]) => messageDate >= date ) || [];
    if (key) messageTypeList[key].push(message);
});

console.log(messageTypeList);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Output:

```
{
  "Today": [
    {
      "date": "2017-04-27"
    }
  ],
  "Yesterday": [
    {
      "date": "2017-04-26"
    }
  ],
  "This week": [
    {
      "date": "2017-04-24"
    },
    {
      "date": "2017-04-25"
    }
  ]
}
```

This way of working (with `setHours` and `setDate`) will deal well with timezone and days that are shorter/longer because of a daylight saving switch, as long as you pass strings to `Date()` which are in local time zone. So they should not specify a different time zone (e.g. no `Z` or no `YYYY-MM-DD` notation).

Comment: thanks so much. very helpful and smart method..

However if today is 27, yesterday is 26, then this week should be 25 and 24. Looks like there might be a bug in your attempt?

Comment: Do you get a different output? I added the output the script is giving for me.

Comment: Strange, when I run the code snippet I get this output:

`{
  "Today": [
    {
      "date": "2017-04-26"
    },
    {
      "date": "2017-04-27"
    }
  ],
  "Yesterday": [
    {
      "date": "2017-04-25"
    }
  ],
  "This week": [
    {
      "date": "2017-04-24"
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: Ah, found it. I should have used slashes in the date notation for setting `currentDate`. Corrected now. It worked for me before, because I am on GMT+1, but when on GMT-6 or something other negative, it would turn out bad. With slashes, the dates are interpreted as being in local timezone. Normally you would just use `new Date()` for that assignment, and I introduced the error in changing it to a more interesting date ;-)

Answer (score 0):

first: seperate your code to functions. it will be a lot easier to test and debug.
second, add 'else', and in  thisWeek() calculate the last monday (as date) and check if the current date is bigger than this date (if the date was after the last monday) - example
messageDate.getTime() >= lastMondayDate.getTime()

The only thing to do is to calculate the last Monday

pseudo:

```
if (isToday(message, currentDate)){
 messageTypeList["Today"].push(message)
} else if (isYesterday(message, currentDate)){
 messageTypeList["Yesterday"].push(message)
} else if (isThisWeek(message, currentDate)) {
      messageTypeList["This Week"].push(message)
}
```